# open GUI terminal automatically using systemd service file

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

I have a shell script that i run with a systemd service file. The shell script executes a python script. The service file works and the script is executed, but i cannot see a GUI terminal, in order to debug. I tried to use

```
xterm -hold -e /path/to/script
```

but no luck.

Can you give me any advise on how to open a terminal with a GUI?

Comment: Service jobs are designed to run silently with errors etc being logged to one or more files.  Why do you need the GUI?

Comment: I need it because i use some sockets and i have prints that help me to debug. I can run it manually and run the end script automatically.

Comment: You could output to a log using the Python logging module or just redirect the output to a file and `tail -f` the log / file to see the messages.

Comment: The question is something like "I want my car to swim". It's possible but no one takes the effort. As already said, a service isn't made for interactive I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/

Using this

cd home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/

nano autostart

Add a @lxterminal in the last line. Press CTRL+X then Y and press ENTER.

Restart raspberry pi OR Type reboot and press ENTER

After booting terminal pops up.

You can use this to make raspberry pi to execute programs at booting. For executing that a program, like a python program that requests an API for information by reading an input.

Add that program in .bashrc file